# TypeScript type with a separate signature for extra properties

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type that defines one static property and where other properties will have a different signature:

```js
type Spec = {
  [K in string]: K extends "foo"
    ? string
    : string[];
};

const spec: Spec = {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: ['a'],
  baz: ['b']
}
```

Apparently, the type checker ignores `K extends "foo"` restriction and wants `foo` property to be an array of strings instead of a string.

How can I solve that?

Comment: @Terry Unfortunately OP's type's properties don't have the same type, so they can't actually use the workarounds described in that question. Howevere, [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQxMZW) are two of the most common workarounds for when the types are different (in this case its `string` and `string[]`); a generic validating helper function, and changing the type of the object.

Comment: @Terry thanks, that describes a similar issue but with a few differences: I don't know additional properties upfront (they should be dynamic) and they should have different types (string and string[]) whereas type in a mentioned question defines all properties as string.

Comment: Yeah, there's no specific type that works this way, which is unfortunate.  See the answer to the linked question for workarounds and consider giving [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) a 